# how to convert markdown to HTML with different sizes using pandoc

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I'm converting some markdown to Html File like this

```
pandoc basic_python.md -t html -o basic_python.html
```

By default, the font-size is quite small in the HTML file I'd like to make all the fonts bigger (title, subtitle, text, etc.). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using recent versions of pandoc:

```
pandoc -s -M fontsize=22px input.md -o output.html
```

Note the `-s` for standalone. The default [fontsize is 20px](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-html).